# How to rotate a text vertically along with it's width

Tags: react-native, text

I have rendered a text and rotated as follows,

```
<Text style={{transform: [{rotate: '270deg'}]}}>Sum Of Potential Revenue</Text>
```

and the result is as follows,

[image]

when i rotate the text, Width of the text remains same that leads to lot of empty space.

Can anybody let me know that how to avoid the space issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link: https://medium.com/@therealmaarten/how-to-layout-rotated-text-in-react-native-6d55b7d71ca5

Sample Code:

```
const TEXT_LENGTH = 40
const TEXT_HEIGHT = 14
const OFFSET = TEXT_LENGTH / 2 - TEXT_HEIGHT / 2
…
<View style={{ width: TEXT_HEIGHT, height: TEXT_LENGTH }}>
  <Text style={{
    transform: [
      { rotate: "90deg" }, 
      { translateX: -OFFSET }, 
      { translateY: OFFSET }
    ],
    width: TEXT_LENGTH,
    height: TEXT_HEIGHT
  }}>
    {text}
  </Text>
</View>
```